# Compress/minify/strip comments from Javascript using PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a mobile web app that outputs a number of CSS,HTML ans JS files into a single HTML file.

I was just wondering if anyone knew of libraries/classes that can automatically compress (and cache) the files before adding them to the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[minify (php >= 5.1.6)](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

> Combines, minifies, and caches JavaScript and CSS files on demand to
>   speed up page loads.

Another good one (which i use with Symfony(php framework))

[Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic)

Comment: it seems to have slower latency and only decrease the amount of data by 10kb than if I just add the JS directly to the HTML. Maybe it will make more of a difference when I have finished all the code.